# XSLT To avoid repeating the template

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

In the XSLT, I have this portion to execute.My problem is, On the output, I am having duplicate data, It is repeating the figure caption 11.3 to after the Table 11.1 and 11.2.  Could you please help me to  avoid this duplication? Please. I am sticking here for a longtime.

```
<xsl:template match="par[@class='image'][preceding-sibling::par[@class='figurecaption'][1]]" exclude-result-prefixes="html">
 <p class="image" style="border: 2pt solid red">
 <xsl:variable name="n1" select="preceding-sibling::par[@class='figurecaption'][1]"/>
 <xsl:attribute name="id">
 <xsl:if test="matches($n1, '(Figure)\s(\d+|[A-Z])(\.)(\d+)')">
 <xsl:variable name="y1" select="replace($n1, '(Figure)\s(\d+|[A-Z])(\.)(\d+)', '$4')"/>Fig<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring($y1, 1, 2))"/></xsl:if>
 <xsl:if test="not(matches($n1, '(Figure)\s(\d+|[A-Z])(\.)(\d+)'))">
 <xsl:value-of select="'Forward'"/>
 </xsl:if> </xsl:attribute> <img> <xsl:attribute name="src">
 <xsl:text>../images/</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 <xsl:text>.jpg</xsl:text>
 </xsl:attribute> <xsl:attribute name="alt">
 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:attribute> </img> </p>
 <p class="caption"> <strong> <em> <!-- <xsl:copy-of select="./preceding-sibling::par[@class='figurecaption'][position()=1]"/> --> <xsl:for-each select="./preceding-sibling::par[@class='figurecaption'][position()=1]">
 <xsl:value-of select="."/> </xsl:for-each> </em> </strong> </p> </xsl:template>
```

and input is

```
<par class="figurecaption">Figure 11.3  Relationship between processes, activities and actions</par>
        <par class="image">gr000032</par>

        <par class="para">A diagram is provided for each <inline style="font-weight: bold;">activity</inline> showing the inputs and <inline class="glossaryrefmain">output</inline>s, including those products that are created or updated by that activity. The recommended actions to be taken to achieve the objectives of the activity are described.</par>
        <par class="para">Each <inline class="glossaryrefmain">activity</inline> is concluded by a table showing the responsibilities for each <inline class="glossaryrefmain">product</inline> created or updated during the activity, as illustrated in Table 11.1.</par>

        <par class="tablecaption">Table 11.1  An example of a table of responsibilities</par>
        <par class="image">gr000033</par>

        <par class="para">Note that <inline class="glossaryrefmain">management product</inline>s created during one <inline class="glossaryrefmain">process</inline> may be approved in another (e.g. a <inline class="glossaryrefmain">Stage Plan</inline> is created in the Managing a Stage Boundary process but is approved in the Directing a Project process). However, the complete set of responsibilities is shown, and those covered by another process are indicated by being shown in parentheses, e.g. (A).</par>

        <par class="tablecaption">Table 11.2  Key to process diagrams</par>
        <par class="image">gr000034</par>
```

Comment: I have issues running your example: 'exclude-result-prefixes' is an invalid attribute for the 'template' element. Also, your input XML is not valid XML, it has multiple root elements. Please provide an SSCCE

Comment: @ThomasW. `exclude-result-prefixes` on a template [_is_ allowed by XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#standard-attributes), which this code must be because it uses the `matches` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
match="par[@class='image'][preceding-sibling::par[@class='figurecaption'][1]]"
```

will match all `par` elements that have `class="image"` and at least one preceding `figurecaption`, which includes all three of the images in your example.  If you want to match only those images that are *immediately* preceded by a `figurecaption` then you need to reverse your predicates:

```
match="par[@class='image'][preceding-sibling::par[1][@class='figurecaption']]"
```

Predicates are interpreted from left to right, so this matches only those `par` elements with `class="image"` whose closest preceding `par` is a figurecaption.

With this constraint you can simplify your `n1` variable declaration to just

```
<xsl:variable name="n1" select="preceding-sibling::par[1]"/>
```

as you know this `par` *must* have `class="figurecaption"` (or it would not have matched this template).

Comment: @lan Roberts: thank for this, It works!! You have a great knowledge on XSLT!! Great